# Passing a pointer to a function in a DLL

Tags: c#, c++, c, pointers, dll

I'm experiencing a serious problem. I have C# code that loads a DLL coded in C that calls a DLL coded in C++. Everything is fine until I'd like to pass a pointer of an array from the C level to the C++ level.

The calling code in C is the following:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <winbase.h>
#include <windef.h>

int sendDLL( int* , int ); 

typedef int (*SendFunc)(int*);

int sendDLL( int* msg , int msgLength )
{
     int status = 0;
     SendFunc _SendFunc;

     HINSTANCE serialLibrary = LoadLibrary("sender.dll");

     if (serialLibrary)
     {
         _SendFunc = (SendFunc)GetProcAddress(serialLibrary, "UssSend");
        if (_SendFunc)
        {
             status = _SendFunc(msg);
        }

        FreeLibrary(serialLibrary);
     }

     return status;
}
```

Now the real twist is that passing the pointer is not enough: the message that is passed will be overwritten in the DLL and we need to read it out once again until the `_SendFunc(...)` returns.

If I start the program from Visual Studio (the highest level - the C#), I get the following right when the `status = _SendFunc=(msg);` is called (that's for sure, if commented out, no error occurs.)

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in TestRS232.exe
>
> Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

It there a way this can be solved?

Comment: How does `UssSend()` know the size of the array pointed to by `msg`? `serialDLL()` takes a `msgLength` parameter which is (presumably) the number of elements pointed to by `msg`.

Comment: You may also be interested in [this article related to NXCOMPAT and DEP](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ed_maurer/archive/2007/12/14/nxcompat-and-the-c-compiler.aspx).

Comment: Probably you should show us the buggy method rather than the one which calls it...

Comment: @hmjd the second byte of the msg array contains the length of the message, the passed msglenth is currently for debugging, I think it'll be removed in final code. (I remove the debugging printf functions :) )

Comment: @Tobias the last DLL that is loaded is tested from other code, working correctly, for my unfortunate.

Comment: Can you remove C# from the equation and run a C app that calls the `sendDll()` function only? I have a very similar problem at the moment with the exact error message that you are seeing. I have C# -> C and it is producing this error with DEP enabled on _some_ machines, but not all.

Comment: @hmjd this seems intesting, I'll give a try, but it's going to take a while.

Answer (score 0):

OK, the problem is solved, the error was a lot more obvious I've ever thought: the return value of the `_SendFunc(...)` was not `int` but `long`, and this caused the message above.

Sorry for the question and also thanks for the help of everyone.

Comment: Are you sure that was the only reason? AFAIK both int and long are 32 bit even on Win64, and both types are returned in the same processor register, so confusing int and long should actually be a "mistake you can get away with" on Windows.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure, correcting the int "status" var to long solved it, though I was thinking the very same as you.

Comment: I second Wolfgang's opinion... Changing from `int` to `long` on Windows can't be the solver. Pay attention to calling convention mismatches: what is the prototype of `UssSend`? Is it `__cdecl` or `__stdcall`?

Comment: Guy _it did actually solved it_ :)
Really.
Even if it lacks any logical reason.